# Routing with multiple parameters in laravel disrupt other one

Tags: php, laravel, url, routes

I want to have a specific URL with 2 parameters for blog posts like:

```
http://mydev.io:8000/@boss/blog_post_slug
```

for defining that in Laravel I use this definition:

```
Route::get('/{username}/{slug}','HomeController@show')
        ->where('slug', '[A-Za-z0-9-_]+');
```

but this definition disrupts any other route definition with 2 level like below:

```
Route::get('/manage/create', 'ArticleController@create')
        ->name('article.create');
```

I would appreciate If everybody helps me how I can have both definitions without any distruption.

Comment: Define the routes with dynamic variables last usually works since routers tend to check them in the order they were defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be resolved if you just define your route with this order:

```
Route::get('/manage/create', 'ArticleController@create')->name('article.create');
Route::get('/{username}/{slug}','HomeController@show')->where('slug', '[A-Za-z0-9-_]+');
```